# How to add multiple applications to different ports using nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, deployment, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

### The Problem

I want to deploy a web app (React) and a mobile app (Ionic React) on the same domain with different ports (using nginx). When I run `docker-compose up` both applications should start running on different ports.

I'm currently running my web app (localhost:80) and rest api (localhost:80/api) with success.

But I 'cant figure out how to connect the mobile application to port 81 with nginx. I'm kinda new to this.

### Source code

My `.conf` file currently looks like this:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass        http://client-web-debug:3000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass        http://server-debug:3001;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}

server {
  listen 81;

  location / {
    proxy_pass        http://client-mobile-debug:3002;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

### Docker compose file

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  client-web-debug:
    build:
      context: ./services/client-web # Location of the Dockerfile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.debug # Which Dockerfile
    stdin_open: true # Enables react-script start to run (interactive mode)
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
    volumes: # Which locations on the local machine must be synced with the container
      - './services/client-web:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    depends_on:
      - server-debug

  client-mobile-debug:
    build:
      context: ./services/client-mobile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.debug
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - PORT=3002
    volumes:
      - './services/client-mobile:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    depends_on:
      - server-debug

  server-debug:
    build:
      context: ./services/server # Location of the Dockerfile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.debug # Which Dockerfile
    volumes: # Which locations on the local machine must be synced with the container
      - './services/server:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    environment: # Variables that can be used in the code
      - NODE_ENV=debug
    depends_on:
      - database-debug

  database-debug:
    image: postgres:12.2 # Download postgres image from Docker Hub
    environment:
      POSTGRES_URI: 'postgres://postgres:12345@database-debug:5432/postgres' # Connection string
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 12345 # Must be specified! You know this by looking through the environment section of the docs
    ports:
      - '5432:5432' # Local port : Remote port

  nginx-debug:
    build:
      context: ./services/nginx # Location of the Dockerfile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.debug # Which Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80 # Application entry port
    restart: always # If crashes, keep restarting
    depends_on:
      - client-web-debug
      - client-mobile-debug
      - server-debug
```

### Result

When I request `localhost` and `localhost/api` everything works.

My browser doesn't find anything when I request `localhost:81`
[image]

Comment: What does your docker-compose code look like?

Comment: @J.ScottElblein Added the docker file. Is it possible that I need to add the port 81:81 to nginx?

Comment: That worked, thanks for the hint @J.ScottElblein

Comment: Happy to help. Just a tip though, docker compose and dockerfile are 2 different things;a dockerfile (actual file) has the code to build a docker image, docker compose is the file/code to configure and launch the containers. I know you probably know this already, but knowing the verbiage will help others when asking for, or giving help. =)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the port you want to access to your docker compose file in the **ports** section:

```
  nginx-debug:
    build:
      context: ./services/nginx # Location of the Dockerfile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.debug # Which Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80 
      - 81:81 # ADD IT HERE
    restart: always 
    depends_on:
      - client-web-debug
      - client-mobile-debug
      - server-debug
```